# Uninstalling Chromium

Tags: uninstall, chromium

I have been trying to uninstall Chromium for a while now, I've tried some of the other solutions to delete the program files, they worked for the most part. The app itself is the only thing now that refuses to uninstall. When I try to uninstall it from the Control Panel and get through the confirmation, nothing else happens.

Comment: If you deleted the Chromium installation directory then Chromium has already been uninstalled.  If you are unable to uninstall Chromium from the Control Panel, a simple fix is to reinstall it, then uninstall it.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Because we do not know your OS, I consider you are on Windows 10.

1. Stop all processes via your Task manager.
2. If you cannot, restart your computer in Safe mode. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6k3eIKBI7a0
   Hit Win+R, type “msconfig” into the Run box, and then hit Enter to open the System Configuration tool again. Switch to the “Boot” tab, and enable the “Safe Boot” checkbox. Click “OK” and then restart your PC when you're done. Then try to clean your system by this way (for example, using software like Bulk Crap Uninstaller, Geek Uninstaller, Revo Uninstaller, Ccleaner... from an USB device). Do not use Internet. Chromium is a legitimate software... but yours is probably a trojan or whatever. After cleaning, restart your computer in Normal mode.
3. Remove all files on your OS relative to Chromium.
4. If nothing works, reinstall your OS! :/

[image]